# Value of Arg(f(z)) after rotation of z

Tags: complex-analysis

An elementary problem asks for Arg($f(z)$) after a single complete counter-clockwise rotation of the point z about the origin, beginning at the point z = 2 and taking the angle there to be 0, with $f(z) = \sqrt{z^2+2z-3}.$

Plotting a few points by hand and then by computer, I find the final value as Arg(f(z)) = 0. The answer in the text is $\pi.$

I am probably overlooking something obvious...thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about $g(z) = \sqrt{z}$.  After you go through a complete counter-clockwise rotation, you find that

$$g(z e^{i 2 \pi}) = g(z) e^{i \pi} $$

That is, a $2 \pi$ rotation in $z$ produces a $\pi$ rotation in $\sqrt{z}$.  Think about this in light of your function.

Comment: Try it without the linear term and see what you get.

Comment: Yes, so you may conclude that the linear term introduces the $\pi$ phase.  This is how a Riemann surface works, by the way.

Comment: Sorry, I was just being suggestive. Maybe I am misreading your last comment, but $z^2+2 z-3 < 0$ when $z \in (-3,1)$.  There is a branch cut (another way of looking at the complex plane) in the plane that is this interval.  For $|z| = 2$, you should see the $\pi$ phase after a $2 \pi$ rotation.  But, if you do not breach the branch, you will not see such a rotation.

Comment: It is $\pi$ because it crosses the branch cut between $z \in (-3,1)$.

Comment: See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_cut#Branch_cuts

Comment: You can say that is $\sqrt{5}$.  But after one rotation about the circle $|z|=2$, it is $-\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Hmmm...may need some time.